# Read TLV encoded data on JavaCard Classic

Tags: javacard, tlv, jcop

I'd like to read TLV encoded certificates on a Java Card (NXP JCOP J3D081, JCOP version 2.4.2, Java Card version 3.0.1 Classic).

The cap file is created successfully, but when I try to install it on the card I get an gpshell error:

> load() returns 0x80206A80 (6A80: Wrong data / Incorrect values in command data.)

I use the jars from JCDK 3.0.3 and this usually works with stuff like elliptic curves etc. What could be different with the TLV stuff?

The applet code used (installs fine when not using the BERTLV stuff):

```
package org.thomas;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.Util;
import javacardx.framework.tlv.BERTLV;
import javacardx.framework.tlv.ConstructedBERTLV;

public class TlvApplet extends Applet {

    private ConstructedBERTLV certificate;
    byte[] certificateLength = new byte[2];

    /**
     * TlvApplet constructor
     * 
     * @constructor
     */
    private TlvApplet() {

        // Register with the JCRE
        register();
    }

    /**
     * Installs applet
     * 
     * @param bArray
     *            the array containing installation parameters
     * @param bOffset
     *            the starting offset in bArray
     * @param bLength
     *            the length in bytes of the parameter data in bArray
     */
    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte     bLength) {
        new TlvApplet();
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {

        byte buffer[] = apdu.getBuffer();
        short incomingLength = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();

        certificate = (ConstructedBERTLV) BERTLV.getInstance(buffer,
            ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, incomingLength);


        certificateLength[0] = (byte) (certificate.size() & 0xff);
        certificateLength[1] = (byte) ((certificate.size() >> 8) & 0xff);

        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(certificateLength, (short) 0, buffer,
            ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, (short) 2);

    }

}
```

I create the cap file by using the following ant build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project default="convert" name="Create JC 3 applet" basedir=".">
<property environment="env" />

<!-- Include properties in the build.properties file -->
<property file="build.properties" />

<!-- Build specific properties -->
<property name="source.path" location="${basedir}/${source.folder}" />
<property name="jcdk.libs" location="${basedir}/${jcdk.basefolder}/${jcdk.subfolder.libs}" />
<property name="jcdk.apiexports" location="${basedir}/${jcdk.basefolder}/${jcdk.subfolder.apiexportfiles}" />
 <property name="target.path.classes"
location="${basedir}/${target.basefolder}/${target.subfolder.classes}" />
<property name="target.path.cap"
location="${basedir}/${target.basefolder}/${target.subfolder.applet}" />

<!-- set the classpath for the tasks and the API, include all jar files -->
<path id="classpath" description="Sets the classpath to Java Card API and tools">
    <fileset dir="${jcdk.libs}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<!-- set the export path to the Java Card export files -->
<path id="export" description="set the export file path">
    <fileset dir="${jcdk.apiexports}">
        <include name="**/*.exp" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="${jcdk.apiexports}" />
    <pathelement path="${target.path.classes}" />
</path>

<path id="capexport" description="set the export file for the cap path">
    <fileset dir="${jcdk.apiexports}">
        <include name="**/*.exp" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement path="${jcdk.apiexports}" />
</path>

<!-- Definitions for tasks for Java Card tools -->
<taskdef name="apdu" classname="com.sun.javacard.ant.tasks.APDUToolTask" classpathref="classpath" />
<taskdef name="capgen" classname="com.sun.javacard.ant.tasks.CapgenTask" classpathref="classpath" />
<taskdef name="convert" classname="com.sun.javacard.ant.tasks.ConverterTask" classpathref="classpath" />
<taskdef name="verifyexport" classname="com.sun.javacard.ant.tasks.VerifyExpTask" classpathref="classpath" />
<taskdef name="verifycap" classname="com.sun.javacard.ant.tasks.VerifyCapTask" classpathref="classpath" />
<taskdef name="verifyrevision" classname="com.sun.javacard.ant.tasks.VerifyRevTask" classpathref="classpath" />
<typedef name="appletnameaid" classname="com.sun.javacard.ant.types.AppletNameAID" classpathref="classpath" />
<typedef name="jcainputfile" classname="com.sun.javacard.ant.types.JCAInputFile" classpathref="classpath" />
<typedef name="scriptgen" classname="com.sun.javacard.ant.tasks.ScriptgenTask" classpathref="classpath" />

<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${target.path.classes}" />
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${target.path.classes}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compile source code to class files">
    <javac debug="${javac.debug}" 
    optimize="${javac.optimize}" 
    srcdir="${source.path}" 
    destdir="${target.path.classes}"
    source="${javac.version.source}"
    target="${javac.version.target}">
    <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="convert" depends="compile" description="Convert class files to cap files">
    <convert packagename="${package.name}"
    packageaid="${package.aid}" 
    majorminorversion="${applet.version}"
    classdir="${target.path.classes}"
    outputdirectory="${target.path.cap}"
    jca="${cap.creation.jca}"
    exp="${cap.creation.exp}"
    cap="true"
    debug="${cap.creation.debug}" verbose="${cap.creation.verbose}"
    noverify="${cap.creation.noverify}">
    <appletnameaid aid="${applet.aid}" appletname="${applet.name}" />
    <exportpath refid="capexport" />
    <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </convert>
</target>

<target name="all" depends="clean, convert" />

</project>
```

The build.properties used:

```
# Source folder
source.folder                   =   src/org/thomas

# Java Card Development Kit folders
jcdk.basefolder                 =   lib/javaCardKit303
jcdk.subfolder.apiexportfiles   =   api_export_files
jcdk.subfolder.libs             =   lib

# Target folders (will be created, no need to adapt)
target.basefolder               =   target
target.subfolder.classes        =   classes
target.subfolder.applet         =   applet

# Applet properties
package.aid     =   0x41:0x41:0x41:0x41:0x41:0x41:0x41:0x41:0x41:0x42
package.name    =   org.thomas

applet.aid      =   0x41:0x41:0x41:0x41:0x41:0x41:0x41:0x41:0x41:0x42:0x42
applet.name     =   TlvApplet
applet.version  =   1.0

# Java class compiler options
javac.debug             =   no
javac.optimize          =   no 
javac.version.source    =   1.5
javac.version.target    =   1.5


# CAP file creation options
cap.creation.verbose    =   false
cap.creation.noverify   =   false
cap.creation.debug      =   false
cap.creation.jca        =   false
cap.creation.exp        =   false
```

So suspected the cap to be compiled with the api_connected.jar, but removing the file from kit, didn't change anything.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance, Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The card simply does not support the TLV classes of the java card API. The JC API is just a recommendation but the card manufacturer may choose to implement a subset of it.

In general anything in `javacardx` is optional (hence the `x` at the end). The API methods in `javacard` must be implemented though. Even for `javacard` packages and classes not all functionality may be available at runtime. For instance, cryptographic algorithms may not be present.

Comment: ... and you can easily implement your own TLVReader/TLVWriter class.

Comment: @vojta Depends on how much functionality you want to provide. For TLV classes it helps to test them using some sort of JUnit testing...

Comment: Thanks, I lightheadedly expected the classes to be available. I should request Petr Svenda to add the availability of the "x" classes to JCAlgTest.